# django ORM merging data

Tags: django, orm, merge

I came across a problem where I could not find an elegant way to solve it...

We have an application that monitors audio-input and tries to assign matches based on acoustic fingerprints.

The application gets a sample every few seconds, then does a lookup and stores the timestamped result in the database.

The fingerprinting is not always accurate, so it happens that *"wrong"* items get assigned. So the data looks something like:

```
timestamp    foreign_id        my comment
--------------------------------------------------
12:00:00            17
12:00:10            17
12:00:20            17
12:00:30            17
12:00:40           723        wrong match
12:00:50            17
12:01:00            17
12:01:10            17
12:01:20          None        no match
12:01:30            17
12:01:40            18
12:01:50            18
12:02:00            18
12:02:10            18
12:02:20            18
12:02:30           992        wrong match
12:02:40            18
12:02:50            18
```

So I'm looking for a way to *"clean up"* the data periodically.

Could anyone imagine a nice way to achieve this? In the given example - the entry with the *foreign-id* of *723* should be corrected to *17* etc. And - if possible - with a threshold about how many entries back and forth should be taken into account.

Not sure if my question is clear enough this way, but any inputs welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Check that a foreign id is in the database so many times, then check if those times are close together?

Why not just disregard the 'bad' data when using the data?